# Elastic Kibana - how to plot error bars

Tags: plot, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I am trying to plot [error bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_bar) to a [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) (Elastic ELK visualization software) plot. I tried to play around with Kibana to see what I can get, but I couldn't get it to work. When I search the web, I don't get a single hit (web page, or previously asked question) for this problem.

Is this capability even possible in Kibana? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as i know it is not possible to visualize the way you would want to.

**However....**
You can use a second metric and a filter on that metric to add an additional graph into the visualization to achieve something similar.